# Chrome extension security: should I check a message's sender ID?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension with a content script and a background page. The background page listens to messages and replies.

Assuming the messages could contain sensitive data or trigger sensitive operations - does my background page have to check for the sender ID, or is there some Chrome built-in guarantee that only my code can send me messages?

If I need to check, how do I reliably detect messages that are from my own content script? Do they have `sender.id` set?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // Ignore messages sent from outside the app.
  if (!sender.id || sender.id !== chrome.runtime.id) {
    // Is this required at all, or the default?
    // does this work for content scripts sending messages?
    return; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Only your code can send messages. To accept messages from other extensions/pages you'd need to explicitly allow it via [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) which uses a different listener. And of course the user may manually send a message from devtools console with the context set to your content script.

Comment: Thanks. Please move your comment to an answer, and I'll mark the question as answered :-)